# Short story in which the president is chosen by a computer among the ones that do not seek power

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

It's not [Franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchise_(short_story)) but I am out of luck trying to figure out the name of the story.

Comment: @charlie - Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: In what ways does the story differ from [Franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franchise_(short_story))?

Comment: @JohnRennie In "Franchise" the computer chose the voter, rather than the president, no?

Comment: I origially read this in the Readers Digest around the 80s....which doesnt help much . it seems from my endless googling that it could be 'songs from a distant Earth' , doubt it is due to it being a full lenght book and not a short story.  in the story I am talking about, the 'chosen president' was "retrieved" from his/her house.....the person was notified and given time to pack and had to go (liked it or not  and in most instances....they didnt like this idea of being preesidents)

Answer (score 8):

***[Imperial Earth](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/117840)*** (1975) by Arthur C. Clarke.

From Goodreads:

> Imperial Earth is the fascinating odyssey of Duncan Makenzie, traveling from Titan, a moon of Saturn, to Earth, as a diplomatic guest of the United States for the celebration of its Quincentennial in the year 2276. Titan, an independent republic, was originally colonized from Earth three generations earlier. Duncan's initial challenge is to prepare, physically and intellectually, for the 500-million-mile trip to Earth. Once there, he is caught up in a sweep of new experiences, including the social and political whirl in Washington, a strange visit to a carefully preserved ancient city once prominent in the 20th century, and a search for and meeting with a woman he loved since she visited Titan years before.

From the novel itself:

> For the last century, almost all top political appointments [on the planet Earth] had been made by random computer selection from the pool of individuals who had the necessary qualifications. It had taken the human race several thousand years to realize that there were some jobs that should never be given to the people who volunteered for them, especially if they showed too much enthusiasm. As one shrewed political commentator had remarked: “We want a President who has to be carried screaming and kicking into the White House — but will then do the best job he possibly can, so that he’ll get time off for good behavior.”

Comment: Good job finding it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.

Comment: I've read that book and thought it was the correct answer, but could not recall enough to post an answer. It might be a good answer for this day and age too, but that's an inappropriate comment (grin).

Comment: I’m surprised to see this given as the answer, since it’s a novel. I read a short story around 50 years ago with your exact description, but have been unable to remember the title or author. It makes me wonder whether “Imperial Earth” was partly inspired by the short story and Clarke incorporated the idea, or whether he wrote the short story and later expanded on it.